# Getting request and response SOAP message when dataFormat is POJO

Tags: java, web-services, soap, apache-camel, cxf

I am using WebServices and Apache Camel and using dataFormat as POJO for requesting that webservice. I am successfully able to call the service but I want to log the request and response SOAP message which I am not able to because the SOAP message is created by CXF from the POJO class.

Is there any way in which I can log the request and response SOAP message when dataFormat is POJO?

Comment: Look at CXF interceptors to log the messages.

Answer (score 0):

this is the example how i am logging soap requests and response in my project, hope this helps

```
BindingProvider bindingProvider = ((BindingProvider) PortType);
List<Handler> handlerChain = bindingProvider.getBinding().getHandlerChain();
handlerChain.add(new SOAPLoggingHandler());    
bindingProvider.getBinding().setHandlerChain(handlerChain);
```

and the class **SOAPLoggingHandler**

```
public class SOAPLoggingHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {

    // change this to redirect output if desired
    public static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("GetCustomerDataLand");

    public Set<QName> getHeaders() {
        return null;
    }

    public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext smc) {
        logToSystemOut(smc);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext smc) {
        logToSystemOut(smc);
        return true;
    }

    // nothing to clean up
    public void close(MessageContext messageContext) {
    }

    /*
     * Check the MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY in the context to see if this is an
     * outgoing or incoming message. Write a brief message to the print stream
     * and output the message. The writeTo() method can throw SOAPException or
     * IOException
     */
    private void logToSystemOut(SOAPMessageContext smc) {
        Boolean outboundProperty = (Boolean) smc.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);

        if (outboundProperty.booleanValue()) {
            logger.info(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:sss").format(new Date()) + "\nOutbound message:");
        } else {
            logger.info(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:sss").format(new Date()) + "\nInbound message:");
        }

        SOAPMessage message = smc.getMessage();
        try {

            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            message.writeTo(stream);
            String msg = new String(stream.toByteArray(), "utf-8");

            logger.info(toPrettyString(msg));
            // message.writeTo(out);
            logger.info(""); // just to add a newline
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.info(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:sss").format(new Date()) + "Exception in handler: "
                    + org.apache.commons.lang.exception.ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
        }
    }

    public String toPrettyString(String xml) {

        try {
            final InputSource src = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));
            final Node document = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(src)
                    .getDocumentElement();
            final Boolean keepDeclaration = Boolean.valueOf(xml.startsWith("<?xml"));
            final DOMImplementationRegistry registry = DOMImplementationRegistry.newInstance();
            final DOMImplementationLS impl = (DOMImplementationLS) registry.getDOMImplementation("LS");
            final LSSerializer writer = impl.createLSSerializer();

            writer.getDomConfig().setParameter("format-pretty-print", Boolean.TRUE);
            writer.getDomConfig().setParameter("xml-declaration", keepDeclaration);
            return writer.writeToString(document);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```